# EWS: Occurrence of a recurrence pattern is sometimes empty. Are there any alternatives?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm fetching all the recurring meetings from Outlook with EWS.

With the recurrence information I'm creating a string with the following format

```
(fromdatetime - todatetime ; fromdatetime - todatetime .... )
```

I need the "numberofoccurrences" to generate the list, but it's sometimes empty and I don't know why.

I also checked it with EWS Editor:

[image: EWS Edtior]

Do you know any other solution to find the `numberOfOccurrences`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Number of Occurrences would only be show when the appointment recurrence type is a Numbered recurrence eg has a Start date (no end date) and a specified number of occurrences https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580960(v=exchg.150).aspx . The appointment being shown in your example is EndDateReccurance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564536(v=exchg.150).aspx (eg has a start date and an Enddate). The Recurrence is a pattern so unless you have Numbered recurrence you would need to expand the recurrence by using a calendarview https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564515(v=exchg.150).aspx to get the number of actual occurrences.

Cheers
Glen